# PyCharm discovering new core Django (rather than app) manage.py tasks?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm hoping to use a newer Django (1.7.dev) inside PyCharm 2.7.3... so it's the only Django version installed in my project's virtualenv.

But, the "Tools" -> "Run manage.py task" list isn't discovering the new commands included in Django itself, like `migrate` or `makemigrations`. (Based on prior experience with apps like South, I'd hoped all available tasks would be auto-discovered.)

Is there a way to help PyCharm 2.7.3 discover and use these new options?

Comment: Update: haven't yet learned a way to have these commands appear in the PyCharm "Run manage.py task" list. It is of course possible to run them outside PyCharm, and they can also be added as custom "Run/Debug Configurations" for alternate execution inside PyCharm.  I'm not yet encountering any other blocks to using Django 1.7.dev inside PyCharm 2.7.3. I suspect the "Run manage.py task" list is [hardcoded-options + app-autodiscoveries], rather than [autodiscovered-built-ins + app-autodiscoveries], because the list still contains options (like `cleanup`) absent in Django 1.7.dev.

Answer (score 1):

the "Tools" -> "Run manage.py task" doesn't see the makemigration or migrate argument.

You can run manage.py with right click on manage.py file in you project.

with this output:

*

```
*Usage: manage.py subcommand [options] [args]
Options:
  -v VERBOSITY, --verbosity=VERBOSITY
                        Verbosity level; 0=minimal output, 1=normal output,
                        2=verbose output, 3=very verbose output
  --settings=SETTINGS   The Python path to a settings module, e.g.
                        "myproject.settings.main". If this isn't provided, the
                        DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable will be
                        used.
  --pythonpath=PYTHONPATH
                        A directory to add to the Python path, e.g.
                        "/home/djangoprojects/myproject".
  --traceback           Raise on exception
  --no-color            Don't colorize the command output.
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
Type 'manage.py help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.
Available subcommands:
[auth]
    changepassword
    createsuperuser
[django]
    check
    compilemessages
    createcachetable
    dbshell
    diffsettings
    dumpdata
    flush
    inspectdb
    loaddata
    makemessages
    makemigrations
    migrate
    runfcgi
    shell
    sql
    sqlall
    sqlclear
    sqlcustom
    sqldropindexes
    sqlflush
    sqlindexes
    sqlinitialdata
    sqlmigrate
    sqlsequencereset
    squashmigrations
    startapp
    startproject
    syncdb
    test
    testserver
    validate
[sessions]
    clearsessions
[staticfiles]
    collectstatic
    findstatic
    runserver*
```

*

As you can see "makemigrations" and "migrate" are in the available subcommands for django

So you have to "Run" - > "Edit Configurations" and add "makemigrations" or "migrate" in the script parameters

Now run the script and it works

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because of how you have added apps in your `INSTALLED_APPS` tuple. So if it's something like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Third Party apps -------------------------------------->
    'south',
    'django_extensions',
    'dajaxice',
    'dajax',
    # My apps ----------------------------------------------->
    'blog',
)
```

Then there should be no problem, and you should be able to find the commands you're looking for, if not, then you have a bug. However, if you have arranged things to be like so:

```
DJANGO_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles')

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = (
    'south',
    'django_extensions',
    'dajaxice',
    'dajax',
)

MY_APPS = ('blog', )

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + MY_APPS
```

Then you have a problem, with 2.7 since PyCharm cannot understand this. So, my suggestion is that you make the tuple the way I showed you to begin with.

Comment: Alas, that's not it. I haven't concatenated the INSTALLED_APPS list that way. Also, the commands like `makemigrations` it's not finding don't come from apps; they're part of Django 1.7.dev itself. (See them for example inside `https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/core/management/commands`.)

Comment: @gojomo Then this is because 2.7 only supported up to 1.5, and 1.7 _will_ come in 3.

Comment: PyCharm 3.0.1 is already out, and its docs only claim formal support to Django 1.5. Still, it's often been possible to use later Django versions in PyCharm, and the autodiscovery-of-commands-in-apps suggests it might be possible for built-ins to be discovered as well. So still hoping for clues to the actual limits or possible workarounds here.